# Android Talkback announcement interrupted

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have activity A with recipes that opens activity B for more options for a recipe.
In activity B I'm doing an action (like adding to favorites) that finishes activity B.
When doing that action, I'm triggering a Talkback announcement so that the user knows the action has been completed successfully.
However, the announcement gets interrupted halfway through because activity B is finishing and Talkback starts announcing activity A instead.

How can I make sure that Talkback announcements are not interrupted? Is there any way to change the priority in the API (similar to live regions?)

I also tried adding a Toast, but the toast announcement gets interrupted as well...

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have run into issues like these as well. I did not find a way to stop interruptions, but generally use the following approaches to get around the issues:

1. Keeping announcements short whenever possible. "Item With A Long Name has been saved to your favorites list" is too long, at that point user has a lot of context and has an expectation of what is going to happen, so short announcement is usually fine. Something like "Favorited"/"Saved" is to the point and takes way less time to be announced! This is important with translations as well, some languages are so much longer than others.
2. **Used carefully and only very infrequently**: Adding a delay. Send announcement, set a timer for 500ms or whatever it needs to be, accounting for translations lengths too, finish activity after that. This is something that ideally will not need to be used a lot: only for very important announcements which shouldn't be missed! Having delays could badly affect user experience, so for me this is the last strategy.